# Error Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' using Laravel

Tags: laravel, iframe

I'm getting a video from `Storage::disk('public')` and putting it an `iframe` :

```
<iframe class="video" width="100%" height="100%" src="{{ route('products.getVideo', $media->id) }}" title="Video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but i'm getting this error:

> Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://127.0.0.1:8000') does not match the recipient window's origin ('http://127.0.0.1:8000')

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Don't use HTTP, only HTTPS.

Comment: @miken32 yes knew that it's something related to `HTTP` but can you please explain why the error ?

Comment: @miken32 I'm setting `APP_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8000` in the `.env` file but it keeps running on `http`

Comment: If you can't configure your server properly, then set the `APP_URL` to http